# How to Show parent_id of Parent_id until parent_id is 0 in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I have a problem when I want to query my database on my category table, I am stuck when I want to show `parent_id` of `parent_id` until `parent_id` is 0.

this is my try
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5dc009/1

this is the result

[image]

and my goal is

```
group_id   |  parent_id   | cat_id | name | variant 

4          |  7           | 4      | Shampo With Conditioner | 1 
7          |  1           | 7      | Shampo Woman | null
1          |  0           | 1      | Hair Care | null
```

Answer (score 0):

Go recursion:

```
function getRootId($id){
    // Select the parent_item which belongs to $id
    $query = "SELECT parent_id FROM table WHERE id=".$id." LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $fetch = $result->fetch_assoc();

    // If a parent found
    if($fetch['parent_id']!==0){
        $id = getRootId($fetch['parent_id']); // go up one level
    }
    return $id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 SELECT t1.id AS group_id, t1.parent AS parent_id, t2.id AS cat_id, t2.name AS name, 
 vr.id AS variant_id
 FROM categories_group AS t1
 LEFT JOIN categories AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.cat_id
 LEFT JOIN rev_variant_cat AS CRL ON CRL.cat_group_id = t1.id
 LEFT JOIN variant AS vr ON vr.id = CRL.variant_id
 WHERE t1.parent!=0 and vr.id>=1
 ORDER BY t1.id ASC 
 LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Output

```
GROUP_ID           PARENT_ID        CAT_ID          NAME              VARIANT_ID
4                     7               4           Shampo With Conditioner     1
4                     7               4           Shampo With Conditioner     2
7                     1               7           Shampo Woman                2
```

Comment: I think I should use vr.id in (id_variant) , because it's will custom in another side